# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Not Recognizing Touchscreen Double tap

Tags: dell, touchscreen, multi-touch

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Touchscreen Display.

Installed the new Dell touchscreen display unit (Dell P2418HT), most all functions work, but I am unable to get the "Double-Tap" to open folders in the Files program, nor can I get the "Two Finger" tap (for 'Right Button') to function in the Files Program.

I connected the monitor to my Windows 8.1 system and all functions worked perfectly right from the start, so the monitor hardware is fine.

Does anyone know what "setting" I am missing here ?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please include the model number / product code of the display unit in the post.

Comment: It is a Dell P2418HT